# Выполнение скрипта в редакторе

Tags: c#, unity3d

В UI есть скрипты Image, Text и так далее, они выполняются даже когда не нажата кнопка `Play`. Как это сделать для своего скрипта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [ExecuteInEditMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html)

> Makes all instances of a script **execute in Edit Mode**.
>
> By default, MonoBehaviours are only executed in Play Mode. By adding
> this attribute, any instance of the MonoBehaviour will have its
> callback functions executed while the Editor is in Edit Mode too.
>
> ...
>
> **The functions are not called constantly like they are in Play Mode**.
>
> - **Update** is only called when something in the Scene changed.
> - **OnGUI** is called when the Game View receives a non-editor-only Event that it does not use (e.g., EventType.ScrollWheel) and does not
>   forward to the Editor's keyboard shortcut system (e.g.,
>   EventType.KeyDown, EventType.KeyUp). Events forwarded to the Game View
>   are enqueued and are not guaranteed to be processed immediately.
> - **OnRenderObject** and the other rendering callback functions are called on every repaint of the Scene View or Game View.

---

Пример кода:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PrintAwake : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Awake");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Update");
    }
}
```

Comment: можно наверное еще про callback перерисовки написать..

Comment: @Stranger in the Q что за перерисовки?

Comment: @AimonZ когда что-то изменить необходимо в шейдере например, чтобы в окне сцены тоже изменения произошли

Comment: @Stranger in the Q А есть ли какой-нибудь callback метод для как в том же скрипте Image, чтобы он вызывался при отрисовки UI или как-то при изменении?

Comment: @AimonZ. я не понял

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если я правильно понял, то изменение кода шейдера/параметров материала приведет к перерисовки Scene/Game View.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker как раз нет в сцене перерисовка не произойдет, там надо городить переопределение методов, это никак не сказывается на результате, просто если есть анимация, то пока не покрутишь сцену значения как будто не меняются

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так это вытекает из того, что `Update()` в редакторе не совсем такой же, как и в игровом режиме. Там нет привычного `Time.deltaTime`, а значит и нет симуляции в "реальном времени". К слову, я даже не знаю, как это можно прикрутить переопределениями, разве что какие-то таймеры вводить.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker постараюсь в понедельник не забыть и посмотреть в рабочем проекте (нет под рукой)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Вот взять создать к примеру картинку на канвасе там появится объект с компонентами RectTransform и Image (Script) далее возьму поставлю картинку после этого поменяю опять картинку  и будет видно что картинка поменялась не нужно запускать запускать сцену и.т.д  любые изменения картинки сразу же вступают в силу мне нужно сделать так с куском кода который редактирует позицию у текста сейчас он у меня срабатывает только когда я запускаю сцену и нажимаю play, вообщем нужно что-то наподобие старой функции OnGUI().